# What is the difference between QModelIndex.model().data and QModelIndex.data?

Tags: qt4, model-view

Going through the documentation on QModelIndex, I noticed that it has a `data()` method to get the data from the model.  All the tutorials I've seen use `index.model().data(index, role)` to get the data at the index.  I thought that was strange, since `index.data()` seems to be much easier to use.

I searched around a bit, but I couldn't find any code using `index.data()` or anything comparing the two methods.

Are these these two methods functionally equivalent, or is there a reason beyond personal preference to use one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are equivalent, `QModelIndex::data(role)` being a shortcut for `QAbstractItemModel::data(index, role)`. It is more convenient if you already have an index object, but the implementation of `data()` is located in the model.